# In Webstorm, to change browser port and URL launched

Tags: webstorm

I'm in webstorm 9 and I can't figure out how to change the web browser from automatically running at port 63342 to 3000 (which is where I want it run from).

That is, when I'm on my index.html, I press the little browser icon in the upper right and it does not browse to the port I want.  How do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your own web server running at localhost:3000, and just like your page to be served by this server? Or, do you want WebStorm built-in webserver to listen on port 3000 instead of 63342? In the latter case, change 'Built-in server port' option in Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Debugger accordingly. To use your own webserver by default, set it up in Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Deployment and make it default for your project

Answer (score -2):

So, the correct answer (using OSX) is:

**Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment**